# activemq no "activemq" file in /bin directory

Tags: java, ubuntu, activemq-classic

I am using (trying to use) activemq 5 on Ubuntu 10.4 and there are big mismatches between the documentation on Apache.org and what is actually in the install.

I installed it by doing a `sudo apt-get install activemq`

According to the Apache documentation there should be a file called "activemq" in the bin directory of the install. However, in my folder `/usr/share/activemq/bin` there is only one file: run.jar which is a symlink. There is no file activemq.

So, I have no way to even start it according to the documentation (http://activemq.apache.org/version-5-getting-started.html#Version5GettingStarted-InstallationProcedureforUnix).

If I try to start a broker using the command `activemq console` I get the error mkdir: missing operand followed by a long java command line which ends with

-jar "/usr/share/activemq/bin/run.jar" start : not found

which is strange because that exact symlink is on my machine.

If I run `sudo activemq console` I get similar errors followed by runtime exception,

> "Failed to execute start task. Reason blah blah FileNotFoundException:
>   class path resource [activemq.xml] cannot be opened because it does
>   not exist. (StartCommand.java:98)"

How can I get past this problem and start activemq?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong definitely. You don't need a packet manager.
I advise you to use the official download page: 
http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-5151-release.html

Pick the latest or other version then download, extract and start via `./bin/activemq start`